# PRIxPtr not recognized

Tags: c++, gcc

I am compiling my code with gcc 4.7.0. My code compiles fine with 4.6.1. However with 4.7.0, it shows:

```
unable to find string literal operator ?operator"" PRIxPTR?
```

I have included proper inttypes.h file. If I try to redefine this, it complains that it is already defined.

Here is the erring code:

```
printf("%016"PRIxPTR" ", addr);
```

Can you tell the solution/workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a space before the PRIxPTR:

```
printf("%016" PRIxPTR" ", addr);
//           ^
```

The reason is that since [gcc 4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html), [user-defined literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#User-defined_literals) are supported in C++11 mode. One consequence is that `"%016"PRIxPTR` is no longer two separate tokens, and one may define (although GCC disallows that) a user-defined literal to do something strange e.g.

```
size_t operator"" PRIxPTR(const char* input) { return strlen(input); }
```

(If you are *not* using C++11 mode but encounter this error, please post a bug to GCC.)